Laravel Links and route not work on server
I'm using laravel 11, everything working ok on localhost, but after upload on server all navbar links not work all pages not found , only home page working.
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('services') }}">Services</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>

and this web.php
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/services', [ServiceController::class, 'index'])->name('services');
Route::get('/login', [UserController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('/register', [UserController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [UserController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/orders', [OrderController::class, 'index'])->name('orders');
    Route::post('/orders', [OrderController::class, 'store'])->name('orders.store');
    Route::get('/invoices', [OrderController::class, 'invoices'])->name('invoices');
    Route::get('/funds', [UserController::class, 'funds'])->name('funds');
    Route::post('/funds', [UserController::class, 'addFunds'])->name('funds.add');
});

all page files in resources/views
index.blade.php
dashboard.blade.php
home.blade.php
services.blade.php

all links on navbar get Not Found:

The requested URL was not found on this server.


Make sure your .htaccess and server config are set up correctly. If it's giving a generic 404 (white page, small black text), then the browser doesn't know how to route it through Laravel. If it's giving a stylized 404, then Laravel can't find the route.

its giving a generic 404, i checked everything and same error

How are you accessing the site? Is it something like http://localhost or http://localhost/public?

access by http://127.0.0.1:8000 everything working ok, but after upload on server only home page work.

That definitely sounds like a server configuration issue, then.

Have you changed the APP_URL in the .env file?
